# How to exit an input at a specific time in Python

Tags: python, input, time, cross-platform

I am new to Python and am looking for a way to stop an input after a certain time. For example, while waiting for user input, after 30 seconds, I want to check the time. If the time is a certain time, then I want to stop the input and move on. I tried using a non-blocking input for this, but I was not able to find a way for it to work. I also do not want to use threading. I am also looking for a cross-platform solution. I know I have a lot of requirements, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading to create an input in one function, and create a timer in another.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os

answer = None
def inp():
    global start_time, answer
    start_time = time.time()
    answer = input("INPUT: ")


def timer():
    sec = 2
    while True:
        passed = time.time() - start_time
        
        if passed > sec and answer == None:
            os._exit(1)

t1 = Thread(target=inp)
t2 = Thread(target=timer)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to use threading

Comment: How come? >>>>>